# Who has the most badge score?

Tags: discussion, badges

Is there a query to discover this?  What I mean is who has the most badges combined?

Also, how would I determine who has the most ordered by gold, silver, bronze badges?

Clarification, how do you determine who most unique badge types.

Comment: There probably *is* a query, but I think the answer is "me" in all cases, by inspection. If you want an ordered list, that would require a bit more work...

Comment: Gold: Jon Skeet. Silver: Jon Skeet. Bronze: Jon Skeet. Reputation: Jon Skeet. Answer count: Jon Skeet.

Comment: These are anecdotes, and seem to be based on self-opinion.  I would question whether this so called "SO God" even has the Tumbleweed badge.

Comment: @ergonaut did you even look at Jon's profile before saying this ?

Comment: @Tensibai, Yes I did, although I am confused with why the profile says 10/23/22.  This is different from fishBelowTheIce's query.

Comment: @ergonaut look at Jon's StackOverflow [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), and not meta profile :)

Comment: @ergonaut I'm pretty sure Jon's have scoring is the highest, it's a fact not an _anecdote_.

Comment: I would say [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) is related.

Comment: @ergonaut Also asking for readymade SEDE queries on MSO is, ehm a bit like asking for _Gimme teh codes plz_ on main site.

Comment: ALL thanks, I am aware of @JonSkeet.  I was, however, unaware of where the documentation for SEDE querying is.  And no offence to Jon.

Comment: @ergonaut in this case you should have asked 'how to ensure/confirm Jon skeet is SO top contributor ?' (I'm pretty sure this would have had a better feedback than the actual question score)

Comment: In most of the cases Jon Skeet is at the top.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I took the SEDE query referenced in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/309358/1079354) and extended it a bit.  It has a break out of all of the users' badges, and you'll see that the actual answer is still...Jon Skeet, hands down.

[Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383770/top-100-users-with-the-most-badges)

Answer (score 38):

Here's a function that you can run to figure out which user currently has the most badges.  The parameter is optional and can specify gold, silver, or bronze.

```
function userWithMostBadges(badgeType)
{
    return "Jon Skeet";
}
```

Note this function only works for Stack Overflow, not other SE sites (or meta sites).

Comment: And it's actually useful for other queries as well.

Comment: This answer should be added on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts. Simply brilliant.

Comment: @Script47:  Sure...if the post weren't locked and thus one was completely unable to edit it...

Comment: You should also mention that it's very efficient, it's ran in `O(1)`. Although I'm sure John Skeet could improve upon that.

Comment: One of the best answers in the history of SO!

Answer (score 11):

According to [this SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/260617/most-badges), it's Jon Skeet by a *wide* margin. At least on Stack Overflow.

There is also:

- [Top 100 users with most gold badges](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/268877/top-100-users-with-most-gold-badges)

Comment: Gold badges are heavily weighted towards users who ask a great many questions. Plus Jon Skeet.

Comment: That gold badge query doesn't include gold tag badges, note.

Answer (score 11):

From a [query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383754/top-badge-counts) we can see that Jon Skeet has the most of all classes. (We knew that already.)

Some other interesting facts about the badge count:

- Jon Skeet has roughly twice as many Gold, Silver and Bronze badges as the next user in each list.
- Jon Skeet has more Gold badges than the reputation of 96.21% of all Stack Overflow users. (99.67% Silver, 99.73% Bronze) [Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/383758/users-with-less-reputation-than-x-y-and-z?x=403&y=5736&z=6865)

---

Side note: How do you get 100 answers on MSO? Ask a question whose answer is Jon Skeet.

Comment: I can't upvote twice for the effort and side note :/